# Soil to buy for potted plants?

Tags: soil, potting-soil, topsoil

Before I ask my question, the only place I can buy from is Home Depot.

With that said, what type of soil should I buy for my plants? It would be soil for planters and pots, and I live in the Caribbean (very sunny and with temperatures currently reaching 98F).

Someone mentioned *top soil*, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Not topsoil, no, if its for pots/containers, you need potting soil, which is specially designed for use in pots and has been treated to remove pathogens which might be present in topsoil and composts. I imagine Home Depot carries a range of different brands of potting soil, so have a look at those. You probably can't get John Innes potting soils where you are, but they are the best for potted plants because they contain some loam in varying quantities, depending which John Innes you buy (comes in No.1, 2 or 3), but a good multi purpose potting soil will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that it shouldnt have foam pieces? Ive seen many bags of soil with small white balls

Comment: That's not usually foam pieces - it might be perlite, vermiculite (both have water retention properties yet improve drainage) or possibly  feed pellets, depends on the formula of the potting soil.

Answer (score 0):

Since, HD is head quarters is in Georgia, I will explain the standards in the US and Canada. 
You are looking for something that says Grow Mix or Potting Mix.  Avoid anything that uses the word soil, even if it called 'Potting Soil'.   This is a heavier blend.  Good for trees and shrubs.
If you are looking for a large amount, you can often buy 3.8 cubic feet bales.  In that case you are looking for #4 MIX.  This is the standards Grow Mix.  #1 Mix is used for transplants, germination and hanging baskets only.   #4 is much lighter and will work in all applications, even hanging baskets.
For smaller sizes the current words used most often is Grow Mix.  This is will be your best option.